# Построение кривых Безье SVG

Tags: svg, вектор

В **SVG** есть встроенная функция построения кривых Безье 2-ой и 3-ей степени, т.е. только по трем и четырем точкам. Нужно строить по произвольному кол-ву точек.

Можно было бы строить кривую произвольной степени, но это не эффективно, и слишком долго, мне надо строить почти мгновенно.

Поэтому хотелось бы объединить несколько кривых второй степени в одну большую.

Как это сделать? Желательно с готовым кодом.

P.S. Пишу векторную рисовалку в академических  целях

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приведу коды примеров сначала одиночной кривой Безье второго порядка, затем с присоединенной второй кривой и третий пример двух кривых с гарантированным гладким соединением.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
   
   <path d="M50,200 Q175,75 300,200" 
         style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:2; fill:none;"/>
 </svg>
```

2. Для соединения двух кривых к конечной точке первой кривой присоединяется начальная точка второй кривой. В этом случае координаты начальной точки второй кривой не указываются.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >
   
  <path d="M50,200 Q175,75 300,200 Q425,75 550,200" 
           style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:4; fill:none;"/>
 </svg>
```

3. Для гарантированного получения гладкого, без изломов соединения двух кривых применяется команда – (T) или (t) (для относительных координат).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >
   
  <path d="M50,200 Q175,75 300,200 T 550,200" 
       style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:4; fill:none;"/>
 </svg>
```

Далее можно присоединять сколько угодно кривых Безье.
Примеры кода взяты  [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=914)

Answer (score 3):

Ну, насколько я помню, чтобы кусочки между собой гладко состыковывались, должно выполнятся два правила:

1. Точка, в которой заканчивается один кусочек, должен совпадать с точкой, где начинается второй кусочек (ну, это очевидно).
2. Эта точка должна лежать на прямой между предыдущей и последующей опорными точками.

То есть, получается как-то так:

[image: Картинка]

*(Извиняюсь за качество, рисовал на скорую руку).*

Готового кода нет, но, думаю, тут его не очень сложно будет написать.

Comment: @Алекснадр Можно пожалуйста, подробней

Comment: @Sithell онлайн генераторы: 1. Кривая Безье второго порядка - https://svg-art.ru/?p=1116        2. Гладкая поликривая Безье второго порядка -- https://svg-art.ru/?p=1118